# Flutter Riverpod UI change only when i hot-reload

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, riverpod, flutter-state

When i call **toggleFavorite** function using a icon button the state is changing but ui not update but when i **hot reload** it's update. i checked some similar question on stackoverflow but i couldn't figure it out.

```
class ProductsNotyfier extends StateNotifier<List<Product>> {
  ProductsNotyfier()
      : super([
          Product(
            id: 'p1',
            title: 'Red Shirt',
            description: 'A red shirt - it is pretty red!',
            price: 29.99,
            imageUrl:
                'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602810320073-1230c46d89d4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80',
          ),
          Product(
            id: 'p2',
            title: 'Trousers',
            description: 'A nice pair of trousers.',
            price: 59.99,
            imageUrl:
                'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1603252110971-b8a57087be18?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80',
          ),
          
        ]);

  List<Product> get items {
    return [...state];
  }

  toggleFavorite(index) {
    items[index].isFavotie = !items[index].isFavotie;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the `state` not `items` :

```dart
   toggleFavorite(index) {
     state[index].isFavotie = !state[index].isFavotie;
     state = [...state];
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I already tried this but still same `void toggleFavorite(index) {
    state[index].isFavotie = !state[index].isFavotie;
    state = [...state];
  }`

Comment: this is how i use provider in icon button is this okay ??  `ref.read(productsProvider.notifier).toggleFavorite(index);`

Comment: this is the provider `final productsProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) => ProductsNotyfier());`

Comment: Please share the code of the list that watches the state provider

Comment: `ref.read(productsProvider.notifier).toggleFavorite(index);`

Answer (score 0):

Hot reload preserves the app state. It's faster as it does not rerun `main()` or ````initState()```. If you want to hot restart the app state, then use hot restart "R" (capital R) in the terminal in debug mode in VSCode or (⇧⌘\ in Android Studio, ⇧⌘F5 in VSCode). See docs [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/hot-reload).